# Map an object from one image to another image using openCV and Python

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, camera-calibration

This is a problem concerning stereo calibration and rectification using openCV (vers. 4.5.1.48) and Python (vers. 3.8.5).

I have two cameras placed on the same axis as shown on the image below:

[image: Sketch]

The left (upper) camera is taking pictures with 640x480 resolution, while the right (lower) camera is taking pictures with 320x240 resolution.
The goal is to find an object on the right image (320x240) and crop out the same object on the left image (640x480). In other words; To transfer the rectangle that makes up the object in the right image, to the left image. This idea is sketched below.

[image: Objects]

A red object is found on the right image and I need to transfer it's location to left image and crop it out. The objects is placed on a flat plane 30cm from the camera lenses. In other words; The distance (depth) from the two cameras lenses to the flat plane is constant (30cm).

This main question is about how transfer a location from one image to another, when two cameras are placed side by side, when the images are of different resolutions and when the depth is (fairly) constant. It's not a question about finding objects.

To solve this problem, as far as I know, stereo calibration must be used, and I have found the following articles/code, among other things:

- https://github.com/bvnayak/stereo_calibration/blob/master/camera_calibrate.py
- https://opencv-python-tutroals.readthedocs.io/en/latest/py_tutorials/py_calib3d/py_calibration/py_calibration.html
- https://python.plainenglish.io/the-depth-i-stereo-calibration-and-rectification-24da7b0fb1e0

Below are an example of a calibration pattern that I used:

[image: Gray chessboard pattern]

I have 25 photos of the calibration pattern with the left and right camera. The pattern is 5x9 and the square sizes is 40x40 mm.

Based on my knowledge, I have written the following code:

```
import numpy as np
import cv2
import glob

CALIL = "path-to-left-images"
CALIR = "path-to-right-images"

# Termination criterias
criteria1 = (cv2.TERM_CRITERIA_EPS + cv2.TERM_CRITERIA_MAX_ITER, 30, 0.001)
criteria2 = (cv2.TERM_CRITERIA_EPS + cv2.TERM_CRITERIA_MAX_ITER, 100, 1e-5)

# Chessboard parameters
checker_size = 40.0         # Square size in world units (mm)
checker_pattern = (5, 9)    # 5 rows, 9 columns

# Flags
findChessboardCorners_flags = 0
#findChessboardCorners_flags |= cv2.CALIB_CB_ADAPTIVE_THRESH
#findChessboardCorners_flags |= cv2.CALIB_CB_NORMALIZE_IMAGE
#findChessboardCorners_flags |= cv2.CALIB_CB_FILTER_QUADS
#findChessboardCorners_flags |= cv2.CALIB_CB_FAST_CHECK

calibrateCamera_flags = 0
#calibrateCamera_flags |= cv2.CALIB_USE_INTRINSIC_GUESS
#calibrateCamera_flags |= cv2.CALIB_FIX_PRINCIPAL_POINT
#calibrateCamera_flags |= cv2.CALIB_FIX_ASPECT_RATIO
#calibrateCamera_flags |= cv2.CALIB_ZERO_TANGENT_DIST
#calibrateCamera_flags |= cv2.CALIB_FIX_K1 # K2, K3...K6
#calibrateCamera_flags |= cv2.CALIB_RATIONAL_MODEL
#calibrateCamera_flags |= cv2.CALIB_THIN_PRISM_MODEL
#calibrateCamera_flags |= cv2.CALIB_FIX_S1_S2_S3_S4
#calibrateCamera_flags |= cv2.CALIB_TILTED_MODEL
#calibrateCamera_flags |= cv2.CALIB_FIX_TAUX_TAUY

stereoCalibrate_falgs = 0
stereoCalibrate_falgs |= cv2.CALIB_FIX_INTRINSIC
#stereoCalibrate_falgs |= cv2.CALIB_USE_INTRINSIC_GUESS
#stereoCalibrate_falgs |= cv2.CALIB_USE_EXTRINSIC_GUESS
#stereoCalibrate_falgs |= cv2.CALIB_FIX_PRINCIPAL_POINT
#stereoCalibrate_falgs |= cv2.CALIB_FIX_FOCAL_LENGTH
#stereoCalibrate_falgs |= cv2.CALIB_FIX_ASPECT_RATIO
#stereoCalibrate_falgs |= cv2.CALIB_SAME_FOCAL_LENGTH
#stereoCalibrate_falgs |= cv2.CALIB_ZERO_TANGENT_DIST
#stereoCalibrate_falgs |= cv2.CALIB_FIX_K1 # K2, K3...K6
#stereoCalibrate_falgs |= cv2.CALIB_RATIONAL_MODEL
#stereoCalibrate_falgs |= cv2.CALIB_THIN_PRISM_MODEL
#stereoCalibrate_falgs |= cv2.CALIB_FIX_S1_S2_S3_S4
#stereoCalibrate_falgs |= cv2.CALIB_TILTED_MODEL
#stereoCalibrate_falgs |= cv2.CALIB_FIX_TAUX_TAUY

stereoRectify_flags = 0
stereoRectify_flags |= cv2.CALIB_ZERO_DISPARITY

# Prepare object points, like (0,0,0), (1,0,0), (2,0,0) ....,(6,5,0)
objp = np.zeros((1, checker_pattern[0] * checker_pattern[1], 3), np.float32)
objp[0, :, :2] = np.mgrid[0:checker_pattern[0],
                          0:checker_pattern[1]].T.reshape(-1, 2)*checker_size

# Arrays to store object points and image points from all the images.
objPoints = []      # 3d point in real world space
imgPointsL = []     # 2d points in image plane, left image (normal)
imgPointsR = []     # 2d points in image plane, right image (thermal)

# Get calibration images
# Get all left (normal) images from directory. Sort them
images_left = glob.glob(CALIL+'*')
images_left.sort()
# Get all right (thermal) images from directory. Sort them
images_right = glob.glob(CALIR+'*')
images_right.sort()

for left_img, right_img in zip(images_left, images_right):
    # Left object points
    imgL = cv2.imread(left_img)
    grayL = cv2.cvtColor(imgL, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

    # Find the chessboard corners
    retL, cornersL = cv2.findChessboardCorners(
        grayL, (checker_pattern[0], checker_pattern[1]), findChessboardCorners_flags)

    # Right object points
    imgR = cv2.imread(right_img)
    grayR = cv2.cvtColor(imgR, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

    # Find the chessboard corners
    retR, cornersR = cv2.findChessboardCorners(
        grayR, (checker_pattern[0], checker_pattern[1]), findChessboardCorners_flags)

    if retL and retR:
        # If found, add object points, image points (after refining them)
        objPoints.append(objp)
        
        # Left points
        cornersL2 = cv2.cornerSubPix(
            grayL, cornersL, (5, 5), (-1, -1), criteria1)
        imgPointsL.append(cornersL2)
        
        # Right points
        cornersR2 = cv2.cornerSubPix(
            grayR, cornersR, (5, 5), (-1, -1), criteria1)
        imgPointsR.append(cornersR2)

shapeL = grayL.shape[::-1]
shapeR = grayR.shape[::-1]

# Calibrate each camera separately
retL, K1, D1, R1, T1 = cv2.calibrateCamera(
    objPoints, imgPointsL, shapeL, None, None, flags=calibrateCamera_flags)
retR, K2, D2, R2, T2 = cv2.calibrateCamera(
    objPoints, imgPointsR, shapeR, None, None, flags=calibrateCamera_flags)

# Stereo calibrate
ret, K1, D1, K2, D2, R, T, E, F = cv2.stereoCalibrate(
    objPoints, imgPointsL, imgPointsR, K1, D1, K2, D2, shapeR, flags=calibrateCamera_flags, criteria=criteria2)

# Stereo rectify
R1, R2, P1, P2, Q, roi_left, roi_right = cv2.stereoRectify(
    K1, D1, K2, D2, shapeR, R, T, flags=stereoRectify_flags, alpha=1)

# Undistort images
leftMapX, leftMapY = cv2.initUndistortRectifyMap(
    K1, D1, R1, P1, shapeL, cv2.CV_32FC1)
rightMapX, rightMapY = cv2.initUndistortRectifyMap(
    K2, D2, R2, P2, shapeR, cv2.CV_32FC1)

# Remap
left_rectified = cv2.remap(images_left[0], leftMapX, leftMapY,
                           cv2.INTER_LINEAR, cv2.BORDER_CONSTANT)
right_rectified = cv2.remap(images_right[0], rightMapX, rightMapY,
                            cv2.INTER_LINEAR, cv2.BORDER_CONSTANT)
```

But I get a bad result:

[image: Result]

I have tried different flags, alpha-parameters, but nothing works...

**Questions:**

- Is it even possible to stereo calibrate and solve this problem, when the two images are of different resolutions?
- Is the general workflow correct or am I missing something? Flags? Alpha-parameter? Other ways to solve this problem?

**EDIT**

After the great comments from Micha I've found out that perspective homography is (hopefully) the way to solve this problem, and not stereo calibration. This is because the objects, that need to be found, is placed on a flat surface at a constant length/depth from the two camera lenses (30cm).

Based on the new information, I've written the following code, where I've used the first pair of images to get the perspective transformation matrix:

```
imgL = cv2.imread(images_left[0])
imgL = cv2.cvtColor(imgL, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
imgR = cv2.imread(images_right[0])
imgR = cv2.cvtColor(imgR, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

ret1, corners1 = cv2.findChessboardCorners(imgL, (checker_pattern[0], checker_pattern[1]))
cornersL2 = cv2.cornerSubPix(imgL, corners1, (5, 5), (-1, -1), criteria1)

ret2, corners2 = cv2.findChessboardCorners(imgR, (checker_pattern[0], checker_pattern[1]))
cornersR2 = cv2.cornerSubPix(imgR, corners2, (5, 5), (-1, -1), criteria1)

H, _ = cv2.findHomography(cornersL2, cornersR2)
```

Based on the perspective transformation matrix, H, I can use the `cv2.warpPerspective()` function to warp the left image based on the right image and the chessboard corners in the calibration plate.

However, when I try to warp it, the warped image (upper image below) is a bit to the right relative to the other (lower) image, as seen on the image below:

[image: Warp image test]

The result of the crop out is shown below, where the areas doesn't match:

[image: Warp result]

I think I need to resize the warped image so it's the same resolution as the right image (320x240). The warped image has the resolution 640x240.

**Questions:**

- Should the calibration plate be placed 30cm from the camera lenses for an optimal calculation of the perspective transformation matrix?
- I have 25 images of the calibration plate from different angels. Is it necessary to use all images, or just one?
- I'm using the `cv2.warpPerspective()`function, but the crop out doesn't match up. Should i use other functions?

Comment: for stereo matching you'll typically compute a rectification which makes pixel-matching much easier. But if I understannd it right you just want to find single points or a set of (4) points in both images. In your case I would search for more general methods than stereo calibration. If you can find epipolar-lines for uncalibrated images you could search for corresponding bounding box positions on the epipolar lines. If you already have intrinsics and extrinsics for both cameras, you could even construct the rays from camera center through the pixels to the scene and find correspinding rays

Comment: Thanks for the input, @Micka. Yes, I think I need some sort of translation, rotation and/or scale factor between the two images/cameras, so it's possible to map an object from the right image to the left image. I.e. so it's possible to do something like: `img = img[y:y+h, x:x+w]`, where x, y, w and h have been found according to an object on the right image and then scaled correctly to the left image.

Comment: there cant be a constant mapping, because the mapping depends on the distance between camera and object. Computing the intrinsics and extrinsics of both cameras should be the same way as with equal resolution cameras.

Comment: Okay yeah, that makes sense. Hmm, and computing the intrinsics and extrinsics of the two cameras is done with cv2.calibrateCamera right?

Comment: intrinsics with calibrateCamera. If you can see the pattern with both cameras you can use calibrateCamera for the extrinsics, too. If you have to use a different pattern for extrinsics you can use (inverse of) solvePnp once you know the intrinsics.

Comment: Yeah, I can see the 5x9 pattern i all 25 images with both cameras with `cv2.findChessboardCorners()` and `cv2.cornerSubPix()` functions.

Comment: yes. To see how a pixel with known depth can be mapped to the other camera, search for the kinect tutorial from nicolas burrus

Comment: Thanks for the answers, @Micka. What if the distance from the two cameras to the objekts is fixed? Say 30cm?

Comment: then you can  validate the extrinsics. What do you hope to reach with the known distance between the cameras?

Comment: Well, to make the problem more simple. If the distance from the lense’s of the two cameras to the object, that need to be found with the right camera and mapped to the image of the left camera, is constant (let’s say the object is placed on a flat plate 30cm from the lenses), then the depth of the two images is (fairly) constant also.

Comment: if the object is placed on a flat plane you can simply use a perspective homography to transform from any image position of one camera's image to an image position in the other camera's image. All you need is 4 different (non-collinear) points on that plane, visible and identified in both images.

Comment: Thank you Micka, I think perspective homography is the way to solve this problem. I've updated the question based on the new information. I'm using the `cv2.findHomography` and `cv2.warpPerspective()` to solve the problem, but I seem to stumble upon some more problems. Is it the correct functions to use? Any requirements to the calibration plate? Thanks for alle the great comments so far (y).

Comment: perfect results can only be achieved if: 1. the object is planar (perspective homography is only correct for the plane) 2. you have perfect point correspondences for computing the homography (subpixel accuracy) 3. camera lenses are perfectly undistorted. Depending on you use-case it might not be accurate enough in the end.

Comment: Hmm, okay. That is a bit sad to hear, but thanks for all your help anyways.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this problem by using the following openCV functions:

- `cv2.findChessboardCorners()`
- `cv2.cornerSubPix()`
- `cv2.findHomography()`
- `cv2.warpPerspective()`

I used the calibration plate at a distance of 30cm to calculate the perspective transformation matrix, H. Because of this, I can map an object from the right image to the left image. The depth has to be constant (30 cm) though, which is a bit problematic, but it is acceptable in my case.

Thanks to @Micka for the great answers.